# Generating random integers >0 that have an expected average value of a given float that is >0

Tags: javascript, random

I'm attempting to generate random integers that have an expected value of a given float value. Below are some acceptable distributions:

```
Expected value: 0.7
Random integers: 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1

Expected value: 0.1
Random integers: 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

Expected value: 2.5
Random integers: 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution so you're able to pick diverse numbers:

```
var EXPECTED_VALUE = 2.7;
var RANDOM_COUNT = 10;

EXPECTED_VALUE  = rando(EXPECTED_VALUE * 2, "float");//DELETE THIS LINE IF YOU WANT THE RESULT TO BE AS EXACT AS MATHEMATICALLY POSSIBLE EVERY SINGLE TIME

var randomInts = [];
var total = EXPECTED_VALUE * RANDOM_COUNT;
var totalRemainder = total % 1;
total = Math.floor(total);
for(var i = 1; i < RANDOM_COUNT; i++){
    randomInts[randomInts.length] = rando(total) + (rando() < totalRemainder);
}

randomInts.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

randomInts[randomInts.length] = total + (rando() < totalRemainder);
for(var i = randomInts.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
    randomInts[i] = randomInts[i] - randomInts[i - 1];
}
```

This solution uses [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to make everything easier to read, so if you want to use my answer, toss this in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: "Expected" can be interpreted as "on average" or "every single time," so delete line 4 if you prefer "every single time."

Answer (score 1):

The answer came to me while writing up the question, so I'll still post it to share my solution:

```
(Math.random() < expected_float % 1 ? 1 : 0) + Math.floor(expected_float);
```

This solution isn't particularly varied or anything, but works for my use case.

Comment: Are you sure this solves your problem well? This will always return `expected_float` or `expected_float + 1`. If `expected_float` is an integer it will always return `expected_float`. While that *technically* achieves your goal, is it really the desired behavior?

Comment: You raise a good point, it doesn't really create random or varied values for integral expected values, but this is still sufficient for my use case. I can see how a solution where the variation can be parameterized or is larger is valuable though.

My use case is picking an integral number of objects to create per frame of an animation (which is randomly parameterized with a float), and the animation has enough randomness and speed to where the integer doesn't have to be that varied to still produce a nice effect. 

Here's the finished animation for the curious: https://brubsby.com/?a=12

Comment: FWIW, the technical term for what you're doing is "[dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither)". Searching for that (or reading the Wikipedia page I linked to) may turn up more useful resources on various ways to implement it.